# How to create and inject a user specific singleton class throughout the whole application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to create a user-specific specific singleton object on Blazor serverside application. Is there a way we can achieve this using .NET Core dependency injection system? I've tried below code. I've created SingletonTest class.

```
public class SingletonTest
{
    private int _counter;
    public int Counter { get { return ++_counter; } }
}
```

Injected the SingletonTest class in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<SingletonTest>();
}
```

Accessing the `Counter` property in index.razor file

```
@page "/"
@inject SingletonTest singletonTest;
Counter: @singletonTest.Counter
```

When I try to access the index page in two different browsers, both are accessing the same single instance of `SingletonTest` class. I there a way I can make this user-specific singleton? once the browser is closed the server need to dispose the user-specific singleton object and call the garbage collector.

Comment: What if your singleton stored a dictionary, keyed by user, rather than a single value? Also, don't expect ++ to be thread safe.

Comment: Are you planning on limiting the number of users that can use the app, or restarting the app pool periodically? This is a questionable design at best.

Comment: This is also what databases are for.

Comment: @3Dave there is no user limitation and not going to restart the app pool. Once the browser closes server needs to dispose the user created object.

Comment: @mjwills is there way to detect the user and add into the dictionary and dispose after closing the browser (after the signalr disconnection) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add Scoped is what you need if you want it to be only available to a single browser instance:

```
services.AddScoped<YourScopedClass>();
```

Another thing you can use is a preview Nuget package:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage

the docs for ProtectedBrowserStorage are are about 40% down on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: `AddScoped` won't work if do just simple refresh. It just recreates a new object.